# How to fetch newest entities from Google Datastore?

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to query entities from `Google Datastore`
 and would like to fetch the **10** **newest entities** based on their time created property, but I am unsure about the functionality of the addSort method.

Will the `addSort` **method** fetch the newest 10 entities if I sort on the timeCreated property and limit the results to 10, or will this just fetch the entities using the default order and sort those results?

> Here is the Query using the addSort method:

```
   Query q1 = new Query("Person").addSort("timeCreated", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort order affects the index that is scanned for the query, so the query (with a limit) will return the most recently entities.